# Asp.net Core rc2 web api file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-1.0

Need help, how I can upload file in ASP.NET core rc2 web api.
When i use asp.net 4.5 it working with this code:

```
   @{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }

 <div>
<input type="file" name="upload" id="uploadFile"  /><br />
<button id="submit">Загрузить</button>
</div>

 @section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var files = document.getElementById('uploadFile').files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
            var data = new FormData();
            for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
                data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
            }

            $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'api/values/post',
contentType: false,
processData: false,
data: data,
success: function (result) {
    alert(result);
},
error: function (xhr, status, p3) {
    alert(status);
}
});
        } else {
            alert("Браузер не поддерживает загрузку файлов HTML5!");
        }
    }
});
```

}

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()  
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
    // путь к папке на сервере
    string root = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
    {
        var filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
        byte[] fileArray = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(root + filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        {
            await fs.WriteAsync(fileArray, 0, fileArray.Length);
        }
    }
    return Ok("файлы загружены");
}
}
```

Now, in asp.net core rc2 it doesnt work, If use IFromFile in mvc without ajax it works, but we use js+ajax+webapi

Comment: It is for Web Api 2 but not Asp.Net Core.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my asp.net core programm I changed the controller method to

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(ICollection<IFormFile> file)
{
     ...       
}
```

I have added the `[HttpPost]` annotation and used the new `IFormFile` interface.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and I solved it this way:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFile()
{   
   //Read all files from angularjs FormData post request
 var files = Request.Form.Files;
  .....
}
```

For full solution you can also take look [on my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144194/iformfile-is-always-empty-in-asp-net-core-webapi)

Comment: Actual in ASP.NET Core `1.1.1`!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Use "Request.Form.Files". Works with ASP.NET Core.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadFiles")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {
        var files = Request.Form.Files;
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

        // full path to file in temp location
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        foreach (var formFile in files)
        {
            if (formFile.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }

        // process uploaded files
        // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

        return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath });
    }
```