# Upload File to ASP.net Core API using Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I have been searching for this for about 2 days and there are many posts about this, but I cannot wrap my head around what I want to do.

**What I want:**
I want to upload a single file to the API using angular, then return the files that are in that folder.

**What I've got:**

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("uploadFile/{regionName}/{propertyName}")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<FileModel>> Post(ICollection<IFormFile> files, string regionName,string propertyName)
        {
            IEnumerable<FileModel> fileModels = null;
            var route = Path.Combine(_baseRoot, regionName, propertyName);
            PathCreator.CreateFolder(route, null);
            try
            {
                var file = files.FirstOrDefault();
                if(file == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("File Cannot be null");
                var uploads = Path.Combine(route, file.FileName);

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(uploads,FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }


                fileModels = FileFinder.GetFiles(route);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(e.Message);
            }
            return fileModels;
        }
```

**AngularJs**

```
viewModel.uploadFile = function () {

            let regionName = "TestRegion";
            let propertyName = "TestProperty";

            let data = viewModel.getFormData();

            let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.addEventListener("progress", viewModel.updateProgressBar, false);
            request.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);

            viewModel.isUploading = true;
            request.open("POST", "/api/file/uploadFile/" + regionName + "/" + propertyName);
            request.send(data);
        }

    /*gets selected file converts to form data*/
    viewModel.getFormData = function() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        if (viewModel.file) {
            formData.append("myFile",viewModel.file);
        }
        return formData;
    }
```

**What is Happening**

this makes it to the API and my file is null every time. I cannot figure out why.

**UPDATE**

after changes
angularJs:

```
    viewModel.uploadFile = function() {

        let regionName = viewModel.region.name;
        let propertyName = viewModel.property.name;
        let postUrl = "/api/file/uploadFile/" + regionName + "-" + propertyName;

        let formData = new FormData();
        if (viewModel.file) {
            formData.append("file", viewModel.file);
        }

        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       // request.addEventListener("progress", viewModel.updateProgressBar, false);
        request.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);

        viewModel.isUploading = true;


        request.open("POST", postUrl);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        request.send(formData[0]);
    }
```

**cs:**

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("uploadFile/{path}")]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile file, string path)
        {
            var formattedPath = FilePathFormatter.FormatFolder(path);
            var newPath = PathCreator.CreateFolder(_baseRoot,formattedPath);

            var size = file.Length;
               if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(newPath,FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }
                }

            return Ok(new {size, newPath});
        }
```

**Request Header**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:multipart/form-data
Cookie:.AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8Jb7vPJ0S0dGnlF8mEfQj9lVY7ccwabgngMkzgRgijxfOqen20J0y2DkgaND5M-EtULRMv8Kun0dSchlF22T6faFlxcybpMs5PhwJ6lRznXHBAV7irCmufJu1NhRUfIvMwQBwj9dE862lPsuKUa3sNh9kUYJ6C2pjiGymMNP25NZfJKwJuMA2ewzD9iZnlk5x5E2UMzbhZH9f6Ks_VPLZ4MlNNerwiLV2mya1QaeOv9AXFi4DKOkEu64IfCNGocipF4wP-anP4FkAN1sZOXJcD52KSruxxoj3Yagl6miAZ1788tT-CBZVvgbSWBHOei7Qcm8BiDdMp6KxtQs30m-_MyrbSnMP2GG26rjDwqwsoXopjU7G3KjLu8lc8dOjZGCGLa2Yc5WF63zOis4_5CZdYwFugqA5Mg1qo8mI5xxoYZVOUR1lWbtV5H-MC2geOMH06B4s_OBt59ZP6IJfIDeKpzcDB-hBmC3EE6pW9-wVSmTwfklyMkR2dsWfrKVcQBcQKUXRhSE8YaL6UARqLXBPP9RTbMV8gybZ6SX3h1lGvsp60wW__cRbo6mKwnko-JH-FiO6ctJzI6ciETCOcaz2QSTMYZVIwEX9CYKR9VKw9MUAZCzFguJSYzSCUPCG8TXGr9MyR6HoMgqCpkHfwc522o; io=7RfOJO9stPcX4wFFAAAB
Host:localhost:57155
Origin:http://localhost:57155
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:57155/Files/Upload
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

**General**

```
Request URL:some url here
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:[::1]:57155
```

**Request Payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryhpPhzjBM0NH4f7IA--
```

Comment: Similar sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads

Comment: Please refer to the answer here
[IFormFile is always empty in Asp.Net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144194/iformfile-is-always-empty-in-asp-net-core-webapi/68310582#68310582)

Comment: Please see the answer here [IFormFile is always empty in Asp.Net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144194/iformfile-is-always-empty-in-asp-net-core-webapi/68310582#68310582)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that the name of the file input element in your form must match the action method parameter name where you receive the uploaded file.

In your example, the parameter name in the action method is `files` but the file input element in your form is named `myFile`. Rename `myFile` to `files` and it should work.

Comment: it is still null.

Comment: You might also need to set the content type like this: `request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")`

Comment: no I am now getting a 500 error that says "Missing content-type boundary"

Comment: Try to use Chrome Developer Tools (F12) or similar to see what the raw post request looks like. Are you sure that the name of the form field you are posting is matching the action method parameter name?

Comment: Can you show the actual request payload as well? Chrome should show you both general, request headers and request payload.

Comment: sure let me try to find it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130857/discussion-between-jamtay317-and-henningst).