# ASP.NET Core Web API IFormFile Empty, When sending FormData request

Tags: multipartform-data, asp.net-core-webapi, fetch-api, iformfile

I am using Aurelia Fetch Client to send a File Upload request to a Web API endpoint. But the `IFormFile` is empty all the tile. My code is below.

Client Side

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("files", account.statement);

const response = await this.http.fetch(url, { method: "POST", body: formData 
});
```

Web API End Point

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save()
{
    var files = Request.Form.Files;
}
```

files is always null. I have followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144194/iformfile-is-always-empty-in-asp-net-core-webapi) and have done as mentioned. But still cannot figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a way to do this using a DTO and specifying the uploaded file as a File object in FormData. This is because I had other field values that I needed to send with the File object.

## Server

Create DTO object with the required properties.

```
public class SaveAccountRequest
{
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Statement { get; set; }
}
```

Add the DTO as the accepted parameter in the controller endpoint.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveAccount([FromForm] SaveAccountRequest saveAccountRequest)
{
//you should be able to access the Statement property as an IFormFile in the saveAccountRequest.
}
```

## Client

Append all properties to the FormData object and make sure you name them according to the name used in the server-side DTO.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("accountName", accountName);
formData.append("statement", file);
```

Post the data to the SaveAccount endpoint. I am using the fetch API to post the data but a simple post should also work. Please make sure to set the content type to multipart form data when sending file requests.

```
this.http.fetch(<api endpoint url>, { method: "POST", body: formData, content-type: 'multipart/form-data' });
```