# Passing a file to server in asp.net core with ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to upload the file to the server using angularjs and Asp.Net Core. I'm trying to pass the file from form as a property of a view model, but it keeps coming to the server as null. It passes the model validation but there is no file in the data coming from the the client side. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or maybe this is not a valid way to post a file whatsoever? Thanks in advance.

C# code:

```
[HttpPost("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]PartnersViewModel thePartner)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var file = thePartner.file;
        var parsedContentDisposition =
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);
        var filename = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath,
            "Uploads", parsedContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"'));
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filename))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }

        //Save to the Database
        var newPartner = Mapper.Map<Partners>(thePartner);

        _repository.AddPartner(newPartner);

        if(await _repository.SaveChangesAsync())
        {
            return Created($"api/partners/{thePartner.Name}", Mapper.Map<PartnersViewModel>(newPartner));
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest("Failed to save to the database");
        }                
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class PartnersViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Href { get; set; }
    public IFormFile file { get; set; }

}
```

Angular post method:

```
vm.addPartner = function () {

        vm.isBusy = true;
        vm.errorMessage = "";

        $http.post("/api/partners", vm.newPartner)
            .then(function (response) {
                //success
                console.log(response);
                vm.partners.push(response.data);
                vm.newPartner = {};
            }, function () {
                //failure
                vm.errorMessage = "Failed to add new Partner";
            })
            .finally(function () {
                vm.isBusy = false;
            });
    };
```

HTML form:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="text-danger" ng-show="vm.errorMessage">{{ vm.errorMessage }}</div>
<wait-cursor ng-show="vm.isBusy"></wait-cursor>


<form novalidate name="newPartnerForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-submit="vm.addPartner()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Nazwa Partnera</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" ng-model="vm.newPartner.name" required/>
        <span ng-show="newPartnerForm.name.$error.required" class="text-warning">To pole jest wymagane</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file">Ścieżka</label>
        <input type="file" id="uploader" name="file" class="btn btn-primary" accept="image/*" ng-model="vm.newPartner.file" ngf-multiple="false">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="href">Link do strony partnera</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="href" name="href" ng-model="vm.newPartner.href"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Add"
               class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
               ng-disabled="newPartnerForm.$invalid" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IFormFile is always empty in Asp.Net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144194/iformfile-is-always-empty-in-asp-net-core-webapi)

Comment: Are you translating your input files to javascript FormData object?